# I am having trouble identifying devices on find my iPhone/iPod

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I have noticed that on find my iPhone/iPod the colour of the device icon usually matches the device. I.e my white iPhone 6 shows up with a white iPhone icon. However my iPod touch ,which I can no longer locate, was black yet when I look at it on the find my application, it appears with a white icon? I am extremely confused as to whether this is my device or not.

Comment: It ought to show the correct colour, all mine do - but don't you name your devices so you know which is which? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBQV8.png Actually I noticed if you leave that page open for 5 mins, they all go solid black after a while.

Comment: Yeah so do mine, but mines just been stuck on white, I had this iPod a while ago so I wasn’t too familiar with naming each device etc. I am extremely worried as I have only ever owned one iPod so am I baffled as to why it shows up a different colour